# My app.py is not able to recive the request at the backend and getting 404 error

Tags: python, post, flask, get

My app.py is

```
app=flask.Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/')

def main():
 if flask.request.method == 'GET':
    return(flask.render_template('main.html'))
 if flask.request.method == 'POST':
    news = flask.request.form['article']
    input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[news]],
                                   columns=['news'],
                                   dtype=object)
    prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
    return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                 original_input={'news':news},
                                 result=prediction,
                                 )
if __name__=='__main__':
 app.run()
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35%;
}
.result {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<head>
    <title>News Classification Model</title>
</head>
<form action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input values:</legend>
        Enter any news:
        <input name="news" type="object" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %}
        {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
            <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <br> Predicted Class of the news :
           <p style="font-size:50px">{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</html>
```

I think I'm having a problem in html file so any help would be great to rectify it.
I'm new to Flask so i'm not able to solve it.My main.html file I've taken from someone so thats why i guess I'm having this Problem.

Comment: `404` error means that request isn't even reaching the flask app. Forget html, check your server configuration i.e. nginx/apache, gunicorn and/or whatever it is you are using on backend to run this app. Also check your firewall if its an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: can you show the structure of your project ? in which folder is your **main.html**? Are you sure you put it in the **templates** folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the blank line between these two lines:

```
@app.route('/')

def main():
```